# Issue importing react-three-fiber and react-three/drei

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber

I'm importing react-three-fiber and react-three/drei in my app.js, but when I start my app it gives me this error:
*./node_modules/@react-three/drei/core/Billboard.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@react-three/fiber' in '.../node_modules/@react-three/drei/core'*
I'm importing those components like this

```
import  React, { Suspense, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { Canvas, useFrame } from 'react-three-fiber'
import { useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei/'
```

somebody know that issue and how can I solve it?

Comment: it's @react-three/fiber since v6, all repos have been consolidated

Answer (score 5):

you got to install the packages. You can go to https://www.npmjs.com/ and  find the install commands there:

```
npm i @react-three/fiber
npm i @react-three/drei
```

Comment: You can also do it in one line:
`npm i @react-three/fiber @react-three/drei`

Answer (score 5):

to add to the answer above, if you use yarn, you can use

```
yarn add three @react-three/fiber
yarn add three @react-three/drei
```

or

```
npm i three @react-three/fiber
npm i three @react-three/drei
```

both packages depend on the three.js library, so it is smart to add the dependency in the command, if the threejs module isn't installed, it will do that to prevent unresolved dependencies